# Grape API in Rails and issues with Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, ruby-grape

Here is what my API looks like

```
resource :service_requests do

      before do
        error!('Unauthorized. Invalid token', 401) unless current_company
      end

      get do
        current_company.service_requests
      end

      params do
        requires :service_request, type: Hash do
          optional :prefix, type: String
          requires :first_name, type: String
          requires :last_name, type: String
          requires :contact_email, type: String, regexp: User::EMAIL_REGEX
          requires :phone_number, type: String
          requires :address, type: String
          optional :address2, type: String
          requires :city, type: String
          requires :state, type: String
          requires :zip_code, type: String
          requires :country, type: String
          requires :address_type, type: String
          requires :troubleshooting_reference, type: String

          requires :line_items, type: Array do
            requires :type, type: String
            requires :model_number, type: String
            requires :serial_number, type: String
            optional :additional_information, type: String
          end

        end
      end

      post do
        parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:service_request)
        sr = ServiceRequest.new(
          parameters.permit(
            :troubleshooting_reference,
            :rma,
            :additional_information
          )
        )

        sr.build_customer(
          parameters.permit(
            :prefix,
            :first_name,
            :last_name,
            :contact_email,
            :phone_number
          )
        )
        #
        # shipping_info = customer.build_shipping_information(
        #   parameters.permit(
        #     :address,
        #     :address2,
        #     :company_name,
        #     :city,
        #     :state,
        #     :zip_code,
        #     :country,
        #     :address_type
        #   )
        # )


        if sr.save
          sr
        else
          sr.errors.full_messages
        end
      end
    end
```

The problem I am running into is that when the `save` method is called, I am getting this error `Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name, contact_email, phone_number, address, city, state, zip_code, country, address_type, line_items`

Here is what my JSON post looks like:

```
{
  "service_request": {
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar",
    "contact_email": "foo@bar.com",
    "phone_number": "111-111-1111",
    "address": "102 foo st",
    "city": "Nashville",
    "state": "TN",
    "zip_code": "23233",
    "country": "USA",
    "address_type": "Business",
    "troubleshooting_reference": "dshjf",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "type": "Unit",
        "model_number": "123",
        "serial_number": "222"
      }
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try using this gem  hashie-forbidden_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Having tried your code locally, I think what you're seeing is normal behaviour. I, too see the "Unpermitted parameters..." messages logged to the console, but the calls to `parameters.permit` *do* succeed and return filtered hashes as you expect. So I think if you check you'll find your code is actually working.

You can silence those messages by adding

```
ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = false
```

either at the top of your class or in a file under `config/initializers`.